# How can I execute a script as root, execute some commands in it as a specific user and just one command as root

Tags: bash, scripting, sudo

I would like to execute a script as a normal user and execute a command that shuts off apache (which needs a root password).

I was wondering if is possible to run the script with sudo but it executes some of the commands with an specific user and executes a specific command as a root.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo -u <username> <command>`

Comment: Inside of the script? and also, how passwords are going to be managed? I mean for admin and for that specific user?

Comment: Yes, use `sudo -u` inside the script. If script is running under root - you will need no pass for any user.

Answer (score 2):

```
su -c 'command' username
```

Been done this way since long before we started using sudo. Both methods work. Pick your poison.

Comment: Very thanks, I use this to make a script to disable some services

#! /bin/bash

sudo -u wachin systemctl disable snapd.autoimport.service
sudo -u wachin systemctl disable snapd.core-fixup.service
sudo -u wachin systemctl disable snapd.seeded.service 
sudo -u wachin systemctl disable snapd.service
sudo -u wachin systemctl disable snapd.system-shutdown.service